# Null Pointer Exception at position variable

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

I am getting the null pointer exception in HomeActivity.java.I am indicated the 54th line in that coding.

**StackTrace:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161): Process: com.fth.android, PID: 3161
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fth.android/com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:54)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3161):    ... 11 more
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.fth.activity;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private ActionBar actionabar;
    private ViewPager viewpager;
    private LiveStreamFragment liveStreamFragment;
    private AppData appData;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter;
    private int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position"); // 54 th Line Error
       appData = ((GemsApplication) this.getApplication()).getAppData();
      Log.v("position", position + "");

        actionabar = getActionBar();
        actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // actionabar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        liveStreamFragment = new LiveStreamFragment();

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                actionabar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        };

        /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

        /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
        fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

        viewpager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        actionabar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

}
```

I doesn't know why the error shows at the position variable.Anybody can help me with these.Thank you.

Comment: remove this if you dont want  `position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position"); // 54 th Line Error` or cross check your KEY values is same or not.

Comment: are you sending any data from other `Activity` or `Fragment` to this `Activity` with that same key ?

Comment: where do you putextra show us that code

Comment: @SimplePlan I remove that line problem solved.I added that line bcoz while playing the video if I click the back button.But it come backs to home page not from that video tab.So that I set a position.But that  line wasn't added anywhere.I doesn't know how to set the position.

Comment: @Raghunandan I remove that line problem solved.I added that line bcoz while playing the video if I click the back button.But it come backs to home page not from that video tab.So that I set a position.But that line wasn't added anywhere.I doesn't know how to set the position.

Comment: @Stephen the point is not removing that line. getInt can return null if there is no value for that key. That is what is happenning

Comment: @Raghunandan ok.I understood it.I created `ActionBar Back Button`.After watching the video If I press the ActionBar back button it come backs to the home tab not to the Video tab.Thats my problem so that I set the position.Finally it leads to error.can you give me some suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if you intent is passed in extras, so:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

if(b != null) {
    position = b.getInt("position");
}
```

If b is null you are probably not getting info through intent...

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent().getExtras()` returns  map of all extras previously added with `putExtra()`.If any data is not added previously then it will return null.

First check whether you are sending any data from other `Activity` or `Fragment` to `HomeActivity` with that `position` key.Also you can check like below to avoid crashing,

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
     if(bundle!=null) {
             position = bundle.getInt("position"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the Bundle object you are accessing is null, before getting the Integer.
Also make sure that the key "position" is the same. I suggest you using variables for that instead hardcoding strings.

Good look.

EDIT:

See Zoran's answer.